# Windows COM C++ - Using delete or Release

Tags: c++, windows, com

Quick question I wanted to ask, I have a Direct2D factory and when I am getting ready to cleanup would I call delete or use release member? I see some tutorials that just call delete explicitly so I was curious to which is safer, unless all the release member does is call delete in the background etc.`

```
Graphics::~Graphics() {

    if (Factory) //Factory->Release(); or  delete Factory;
    if (Render) //Render->Release();  or delete Render;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to release COM interfaces is to call the `Release` method on the interface pointer.

`delete` is for C++ objects allocated with `new` on the heap, not for COM interface pointers.

Note that you can also safely wrap raw COM interface pointers using smart pointer classes like ATL's `CComPtr`. In this case, the `Release` method is called *automatically* when the smart pointer goes out of scope.

For example, if you use smart pointer wrappers for the `Factory` and `Render` data members in your example, there's no need to explicitly call `Release` in the `Graphics` destructor: the C++ compiler will *automatically* call the destructors on each data member, which will result in `Release` being called for the wrapped COM interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

of course `Release();` and only this on interface method. and you can call `delete` only for memory which you previous allocated by own `new`. always error call `delete` for memory allocated from external `DLL` because they new/delete can not match your new/delete

Comment: " always error call delete for memory allocated from external DLL because they new/delete can not match your new/delete" isn't quite true. It's possible for two or more Windows modules to use the same instance of the same runtime library, namely with the runtime library as a DLL. It's also possible to define class-specific allocation and deallocation that takes care of using the proper instance-specific memory manager.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - of course quite possible that 2 different `pe` modules have the same implementation of `new/delete` - so this formal will be worked, but event in this case this will be logic error.

Comment: No, there's no logic error when you do something that's entirely OK for the code that you control.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - if one module allocate memory and pass this memory to another module, which must free it when it is no longer needed - must be clearly stated - which api use for free (`LocalFree` for example). `delete` - this is only place holder, not concrete function (can be different implementations) - as result `delete` never can be used for free memory allocated from another module. say memory allocated with `LocalAlloc` and we call `delete` for it ? are this will be crash or memory leak ? not mandatory. if our implementation of delete used `LocalFree` - all will be worked fine.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - but this anyway logical error use `delete` for external and unknown way allocated memory

Comment: Apparently you're overgeneralizing the restrictions in the general case to be an absolute rule. I think one good approach for studying this is to delve into how Visual C++ supports returning a `std::string` from a DLL function. If it does. ;-)